# Type Lumina is prequel to Actress Code?

Tags: tsukihime, melty-blood-series

I don’t understand because I'm a novice with tsukihime series. Melty Blood Type Lumina is prequel to Melty Blood Actress Against Current Code?

Just because Lumina have less playable charactes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of.

[Melty Blood Actress Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melty_Blood#Actress_Again) is the fourth game in the Melty Blood fighting game series, while *Melty Blood Actress Again Current Code* is an arcade port of the PS2 version.

[Melty Blood: Type Lumina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melty_Blood:_Type_Lumina) is the fifth game of *Melty Blood* fighting game series. Unlike the previous four games, it takes place in the **reboot timeline**.
*Type Lumina* is a **prequel** fighting game featuring the characters as depicted in the *Tsukihime* visual novel remake title -*A piece of blue glass moon*-, and originally meant to serve as a "what-if scenario".

To answer OP's comment, this is the current timeline:

[image]

The green timelime is the *Original Tsukihime Timeline*, while Lumina is the first title of *Tsukihime Remake Timeline*.

Comment: So, "what-if scenario" and reboot means even another timeline and means next titles(games) ??

Comment: @reOrion it's something that happens in an alternative timeline, not following the main arc of the story. So yes, it may have other own sequels.

Comment: well thanks for answer, wish it have meme cat...